# Bot framework continue conversation doesn't work

Tags: python, callback, botframework, asynccallback

I'm trying to get a bot to reply to an existing conversation through a separate function.
My code looks as follows.

```
   class TestClass():
    
    def callback(self, message):
        async def async_callback(turn_context):
            await turn_context.send_activity(message)
        return async_callback

    async def testReply(self, message):
        conversation_reference = shared_storage[self.user_id]
        adapter = MyBotAdapter()
        await adapter.continue_conversation(conversation_reference, self.callback(message))    
        print("OUTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT")


class TestBot(ActivityHandler):
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
               conversation_reference = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
        self.user_id = turn_context.activity.from_property.id
        shared_storage[self.user_id] = conversation_reference


        other_class = TestClass(self.user_id)
        await other_class.testReply(turn_context.activity.text)
```

There are no errors but testReply doesn't reply at all. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

app.py:

```py
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License.

import sys
import traceback
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from http import HTTPStatus
from typing import Dict

from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web import Request, Response, json_response
from botbuilder.core import (
    TurnContext,
)
from botbuilder.core.integration import aiohttp_error_middleware
from botbuilder.integration.aiohttp import CloudAdapter, ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes, ConversationReference

from bots import ProactiveBot
from config import DefaultConfig

CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

# Create adapter.
# See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about how bots work.
ADAPTER = CloudAdapter(ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication(CONFIG))

# Catch-all for errors.
async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):
    # This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    # NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    #       application insights.
    print(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}", file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()

    # Send a message to the user
    await context.send_activity("The bot encountered an error or bug.")
    await context.send_activity(
        "To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code."
    )
    # Send a trace activity if we're talking to the Bot Framework Emulator
    if context.activity.channel_id == "emulator":
        # Create a trace activity that contains the error object
        trace_activity = Activity(
            label="TurnError",
            name="on_turn_error Trace",
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            type=ActivityTypes.trace,
            value=f"{error}",
            value_type="https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
        )
        # Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
        await context.send_activity(trace_activity)


ADAPTER.on_turn_error = on_error

# Create a shared dictionary.  The Bot will add conversation references when users
# join the conversation and send messages.
CONVERSATION_REFERENCES: Dict[str, ConversationReference] = dict()

# If the channel is the Emulator, and authentication is not in use, the AppId will be null.
# We generate a random AppId for this case only. This is not required for production, since
# the AppId will have a value.
APP_ID = ...YOUR APP ID HERE

# Create the Bot
BOT = ProactiveBot(CONVERSATION_REFERENCES)


# Listen for incoming requests on /api/messages.
async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:
    # Main bot message handler.
    if "application/json" in req.headers["Content-Type"]:
        body = await req.json()
    else:
        return Response(status=HTTPStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)
    auth_header = req.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in req.headers else ""

    response = await ADAPTER.process_activity(auth_header, activity, BOT.on_turn)
    if response:
        return json_response(data=response.body, status=response.status)
    return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK)


# Listen for requests on /api/notify, and send a messages to all conversation members.
async def notify(req: Request) -> Response:  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    await _send_proactive_message()
    return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK, text="Proactive messages have been sent")


# Send a message to all conversation members.
# This uses the shared Dictionary that the Bot adds conversation references to.
async def _send_proactive_message():
    for conversation_reference in CONVERSATION_REFERENCES.values():
        await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
            conversation_reference,
            lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity("proactive hello"),
            APP_ID,
        )


APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
APP.router.add_get("/api/notify", notify)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="localhost", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

bot.py:

```py
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License.

from typing import Dict

from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount, ConversationReference, Activity


class ProactiveBot(ActivityHandler):
    def __init__(self, conversation_references: Dict[str, ConversationReference]):
        self.conversation_references = conversation_references

    async def on_conversation_update_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        self._add_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
        return await super().on_conversation_update_activity(turn_context)

    async def on_members_added_activity(
        self, members_added: [ChannelAccount], turn_context: TurnContext
    ):
        for member in members_added:
            if member.id != turn_context.activity.recipient.id:
                await turn_context.send_activity(
                    "Welcome to the Proactive Bot sample.  Navigate to "
                    "http://localhost:3978/api/notify to proactively message everyone "
                    "who has previously messaged this bot."
                )

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        self._add_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
        return await turn_context.send_activity(
            f"You sent: {turn_context.activity.text}"
        )

    def _add_conversation_reference(self, activity: Activity):
        """
        This populates the shared Dictionary that holds conversation references. In this sample,
        this dictionary is used to send a message to members when /api/notify is hit.
        :param activity:
        :return:
        """
        conversation_reference = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(activity)
        self.conversation_references[
            conversation_reference.user.id
        ] = conversation_reference
```

This code will provide an endpoint on http://localhost:3978/api/notify (GET) that every time requested, it's gonna send a proactive notify to users that had sent messages before.

I was stuck on the same problem than you, so I cloned the botbuilder-samples repo and I've implemented this approach based on the sample **botbuilder-samples/samples/bot-samples/16.proactive-messages** on the repo.

Here's the link of the [github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples.git) where this code was based, and here's the contributing [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python).